# Lie algebra of a symplectic group $Sp(n)$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-algebras

The symplectic group is defined as $Sp(n)=\{A\in GL(n,\mathbb{H}) \vert \bar A^TA=I\}.$ Show the tangent space at the identity $I$ of the symplectic group $Sp(n)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{H})$ is the vector space of all $n\times n $ quaternionic matrices $X$ such that $\bar X^T=-X$.

The main difficulty for me is that I don't know what it means quaternion matrices and the symplectic group of this form.

Comment: A **quaternion matrix** is one where the entries are quaternions. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)